# Pinterest post structure

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How one can build a site structure like [Pinterest](http://www.pinterest.com/)?
I mean each post has it's own height (with is determined by backend programming).

I'm trying to do it, but what I have now is this:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">


 {% for key, values in prodmatrix %}

 <li class="span3">
<div class="product-box">
<span class="sale_tag"></span>
<p><a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{values.1.0}}" alt="" /></a></p>
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}" class="title"><h4>{{ values.0.0 }}</h4></a><br/>
<p class="category"><a href="{% url 'product_detail' slug=values.3.0 %}">{{values.2.0}} {{values.2.1}} {{values.2.2}}</a></p>

</div>

</li>
 {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Which don't work really well, as you can see [here](http://www.consumers2products.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some similar questions might help you:

- [CSS3 Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641827/css3-multiple-columns)
- [Pinterest style layout (Bootstrap 3 + Masonary) *final tweeks*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462853/pinterest-style-layout-bootstrap-3-masonary-final-tweeks)
- [How to display a grid with text like Pinterest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963988/how-to-display-a-grid-with-text-like-pinterest/)
- [CSS code for pinterest layout style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968132/css-code-for-pinterest-layout-style)